# symbol of a potentiometer with a buoy to work as a level sensor

Tags: potentiometer, circuits

I am designing a circuit and I am going to use a potentiometer with a buoy to work as a level sensor. What symbol do I have to put?

Comment: https://symbols.radicasoftware.com/225/iec-symbols might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nearest is a fuel level sensor symbol.

[image]

https://www.slideshare.net/RooDacayan/electrical-symbols-84628126

Comment: Thank you, Sonlas 10.

Answer (score 2):

On a schematic, I'd just put a normal potentiometer symbol, with a note beside it indicating the function.